# Network Load Balancer can not find in aws by Java SDK (v1 & v2)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-java-sdk-2.x, network-load-balancer

**I want to get list of NLB(Network-Load-balancer) in specific region by AWS Java SDK from AWS.**

Here is my sample Code:

```
ElasticLoadBalancingClient loadBalancingClient = ElasticLoadBalancingClient.builder ().credentialsProvider (
                StaticCredentialsProvider.create (AwsBasicCredentials.create (
                        "****", "*****")))
        .region (Region.of ("us-east-2")).build ();

DescribeLoadBalancersResponse result = loadBalancingClient.describeLoadBalancers ();
List<LoadBalancerDescription> descriptionList = result.loadBalancerDescriptions ();
System.out.println ("Size: " + descriptionList.size ());
```

using this procedure i get all classic load-balancer but when i create NLB in AWS. Its give me empty as a result. Means sdk do not detect NLB as a load-balancer. How can i fix this issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Network load balancers, use **Elastic Load Balancing v2 Client**.

**Sample Code:**

```
ElasticLoadBalancingV2Client loadBalancingV2Client = ElasticLoadBalancingV2Client.builder ()
                        .credentialsProvider (StaticCredentialsProvider.create (
                                AwsBasicCredentials.create (*****,*****)))
                        .region (Region.of (*****))
                        .build ();
DescribeLoadBalancersResponse result = loadBalancingV2Client.describeLoadBalancers ();
```

This is specify in the documentation: "This reference covers the 2015-12-01 API, which supports Application Load Balancers and Network Load Balancers. The 2012-06-01 API supports Classic Load Balancers."